# What could be the reason for Puppeteer not launching in Ubuntu server?

Tags: web-scraping, amazon-ec2, puppeteer

```
const puppeteer       = require('puppeteer');  
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
const page = await browser.newPage();
```

This is my puppeteer implementation to scrape a web page. This is working locally but throwing a browser is undefined error when deployed to my EC2 ubuntu server.

why is browser undefined the moment i deploy to an EC2 ubuntu server but it works locally.

Comment: Can you please share the logs?

Comment: The error is "browser is undefined".

Comment: do you have the Configuration file and .cache folder for your puppeteer in the project root directory? if not please follow the documentation to create both. https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration
I had a similar issue where it was working locally but I was getting 
Error: Could not find Chromium
on Heroku and following the above solved my problem.